# Python 3 C API. Initialising MIMEText object fails

Tags: python

I am looking to embed Python into a C program. Among other things Python will look after sending email. I have no trouble using the base types from C, but I have trouble using other objects within the library.

I am looking to instantiate a MIMEText instance by:

```
PyObject *mimeTextModule = PyImport_ImportModule("email.mime.text");    
PyObject* sys_mod_dict = PyImport_GetModuleDict();
PyObject* main_mod = PyMapping_GetItemString(sys_mod_dict, "__main__");
PyObject* mimeText = PyObject_CallMethod(main_mod, "MIMEText", "s", "test email body");
```

but mimeText is NULL. I have also tried the below, with the same result:

```
PyObject *mimeTextModule = PyImport_ImportModule("email.mime.text");    
PyObject *mimeTextClass = PyObject_GetAttrString(mimeTextModule, "MIMEText");
PyObject *mimeText = PyObject_CallMethod(mimeTextClass, "__init__", "s", "test email body");
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `NULL` means that an exception occurred and you need to [check what it is](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/exceptions.html).

If you want to instantiate a class then you do it the same way in C as you do in Python: [call it](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/object.html#PyObject_Call).